# ¿Hay forma de modificar el scroll de un textarea sin modificar la esquina del resize?

Tags: css, textarea

Quiero reducir el ancho del scroll, pero el resize no se reduzca.
[image: Textarea normal sin texto incluido, entonces no aparece aun el scroll]

[image: aparece el scroll, pero provoca que se reduzca el resize]

Comment: Muestra lo que has intentado hasta el momento: lee [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Esta es una forma para cambiarle el color y las dimensiones de la barra de desplazamiento:

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar{
   background: #090909;
   width: 13px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
    background: #252525;
    width: 15px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover{
    background-color: #333;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active{
    background-color: #555;
}
```

1. Para el resize puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```css
textarea.example {
  resize: none; /* disables resizability */
}
```

Comment: pero el resize: none provoca que desaparezca, no quiero eso, lo que quiero es reducir el ancho del scroll, pero no el ancho del resize, no sé si es posible.